# Blockquote Spacing - Remove Leading/Trailing Blank Lines

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a table of contents using blockquote tags. However, I cannot seem to get the spacing correct. Apparently a new blockquote tag adds a blank line before and after. I need to get rid of those lines but cannot seem to figure out what parameter does it. Here is my CSS that I thought should work:

```
.toc {
   text-align:left;
   margin-bottom:0 em;
   margin-top:0 em;
}
```

Can someone help me with the correct style to do that? TIA.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @Paulie_D I beg to differ, because there is a lesson to be learned from this. I feel that others might also run into the problem of separating the value and unit, and they may not feel that it is a "typo." I tried to explain this with documentation.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3Schools.com:

> A whitespace cannot appear between the number and the unit. However, if the value is 0, the unit can be omitted.

Therefore, the correct code would be:

```
.toc {
   text-align:left;
   margin-bottom: 0em;
   margin-top: 0em;
}
```

Or simply:

```
.toc {
   text-align:left;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

Check it out:

```css
p, blockquote {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<blockquote>This is a blockquote</blockquote>
<p>I removed margins on <code>&lt;p&gt;</code> elements as well so that their margins would not be mistaken for blockquote's margins.</p>
```

Comment: Neither seemed to work for me. I decided to abandon this approach and used <pre> instead. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @WtRiker Don't give up! `<pre>` doesn't have the same purposes as `<blockquote>`.  Check the box model using "Inspect element" to see if anything else could be contributing to the extra space-- I can't tell you if it is because you didn't show any HTML or any more CSS

Comment: Dumb me. It occurred to me that what I am really asking for is an unordered list but without bullets. I did not realize until just now bullets could be turned off completely with "list-style-type:none". I have what I want now.